# How to fix 'toggle between images in owl carousel the content moves to top'

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I am working on the project, here is my live link to the site code **[My link](http://web.customfactory.pk/Product/Detail/7)**
Here u will see the owl slider of the product. when I toggle between the images the images and the whole content is moved to the top of the page behind the fixed header.
**what I want is that the screen remain still and do not move or scroll to top or bottom**

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to see your code on Stack Overflow, not a link; also what you tried. Thanks.

Comment: That's because you used an anchor tag with images navigation.

Comment: @Guillaume my code is too large that's why I just included the link so that everyone can see it. I have tried something that's why I am facing an error.

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies but if I remove it I am unable to toggle b/w images
what is the alternative for it how to achieve it without an anchor tag ?

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies will u help me please ?

Comment: @gohar Below answer seems correct to me.

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies but with that I am unable to toggle the images in slider

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag that you're using. Maybe try using this:

```
$(".horizontal-thumb ").click(function(e) {
   // change slider image
   // do something else

   e.preventDefault(); // this is what you need
})
```

Comment: How to change the slider image ? will u please help ?